# PHP: How to check for and uppercase specific parts of a string?

Tags: php, string, function

How to format specific parts of a string?

In this case, I have a form that asks users for an address, and it posts to php as a variable that I catch with `$_POST`, and turn it into a variable which I output like the following to make it look cleaner:

```
$receive_address = ucwords(strtolower(str_replace('.','',$_POST['send_address'])));
```

The address would be entered into the form like this...

> 100 john st., toronto, on

...and be outputted as this...

> 100 John St, Toronto, On

If I enter `100 john st., toronto`, on, or `100 john st., toronto, ontario`, I want the final result to be this:

> 100 John St, Toronto, ON

Literally the only difference is that the final result will conclude with the province in 2 letters, capitalized.

I want to take it a step further and check to see if there is an "On" in there at the end, and if there isn't to add it, and if there is, to capitalize both letters.

Is this possible, and how would this work?

---

Here's my attempt at figuring this out:

```
function findProvCode($address_data) {
    $prov_codes = array('NL','PE','NS','NB','QC','ON',' MB','SK','AB','BC','YT','NT','NU')
    if (stripos($address_data, $prov_codes)) {
        // still need to find out which of the prov codes it is...
        // $specify_code = something to do with finding out which code this address already had
        str_replace('$address_data',strtoupper($specify_code),$address_data);
    } 
}
```

Here's a PHP sandbox of where I'm at so far... someone had posted an answer with some ideas but deleted it (assuming because it didn't work the way they had intended), those ideas were useful though: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/36f1e07e2e52573e230da4dda49320c564a818cd

The workflow seems simple...

1 - check for province or province code

2 - if province code, uppercase it

3 - if whole word, change to province code and uppercase province code

Just not sure how to do this.

---

I know this really isn't that important in reality... I just want to learn how to manipulate a string this way.

Comment: would you please post an example here, like if you input '__SOMESTUFF__' what should be the kind of ouput?

Comment: @ameenulla0007 just updated

Comment: Check [ucwords()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php)

Comment: @Yuri I could capitalize the whole thing, I just want to capitalize the country code though.

Comment: You can only make a string replacement, given you already have codes and cities. You could even send request to some map API, but it would take longer than a `str_replace()`

Comment: Given my attempt above, how would I find out (within that function) which province code was already there? Since I'm searching to see if any one of the codes within that array are there - that's where I think I'm stuck.

Comment: two quick questions, 1. is country code an mandatory input? 2. is country code always exists at the end?

Comment: @ameenulla0007 thanks for taking interest, it isn't technically mandatory, I know I could make it 3 separate inputs and concatenate the values together, this is more of a learning experience though so I want to do it the hard way in this case. There should always be a province code at the end though.

Comment: Change to `str_replace($fullnames, $prov_codes, $address_data);`
Element in $fullnames and $prov_codes need to match index, so if Ontario is index 8, it will be the same for both array.

Comment: @Yuri this is where I'm at so far... I've done what you asked actually: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b1f59b359c7bf18fe920d7ded6d86c6c63bddc97

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this at the end of your code:

```
$address_string = "100 John St, Toronto, On";

$address_array = explode(',', $address_string);
array_push($address_array, strtoupper(array_pop($address_array)));
$address_string = implode(',', $address_array);
```

**OR**, if you prefer a function:

```
function CapProvCode($address_string){
    $address_array = explode(',', $address_string);
    array_push($address_array, strtoupper(array_pop($address_array)));
    return implode(',', $address_array);
}
```

Where $address_string is the string which the two last letters will be capitalized.

I've tried them here and I got the following output after a `echo $address_string;`

> 100 John St, Toronto, ON

---

Explaning what happened:

The [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function breaks the string everytime it finds a ',' (delimiter) and return the pieces into an array. So, after the first line, $address_array is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 100 John St
    [1] =>  Toronto
    [2] =>  On
)
```

On second line we will analyse piece after piece. The most inside nest, [array_pop](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php), take out the last item of `$address_array` and we got this

**second line in progress**

```
array_push($address_array, strtoupper(" On"));
```

**print_r() of $address_array at this moment**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 100 John St
    [1] =>  Toronto
)
```

Now the function strtoupper() capitalize the string " On". On the outter nest, [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) insert the string capitalized at the last position of `$address_array`:

**print_r() of $address_array after second line is evaluated**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 100 John St
    [1] =>  Toronto
    [2] =>  ON
)
```

Then, on third line, [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) make the oposit of explode, join all pieces of an array into a string and separating them by ','. That's it!

---

**Solving with Regular Expressions**

To work with the possibility of a string like `100 John St, Toronto, On, Canada`, you have to deal with [Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). They are really not easy to understand and even harder to write, but definetly worth to learn how and when to use them. *Regex* are useful when you are dealing with string patterns.

Php has a native function to replace strings using *regex*: [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). Take a look at this code, it should do the trick:

```
$address_string[] = "100 John St, Toronto, On, Canada";
$address_string[] = "100 John St, Toronto, on, Canada";
$address_string[] = "100 John St, Toronto, On";
$address_string[] = "100 John St, Toronto, on";

foreach($address_string as $value){
    echo preg_replace('/, [A-za-z]{2}(,|$)/e', 'strtoupper("$0")', $value);
    echo "<br>";
}
```

I executed it and the output is:

> 100 John St, Toronto, ON, Canada
>
> 100 John St, Toronto, ON, Canada
>
> 100 John St, Toronto, ON
>
> 100 John St, Toronto, ON

I hope it works for all cases. Don't give up easily when trying to understand regex, they are really hard. [This](http://regexr.com/) can help you.

Comment: Wow, talk about providing a shorter answer than I thought would even work lol... and it works perfectly. I honestly don't understand how it's targeting the province code?? Could you help me understand it?

Comment: @Matthew I tried to explain on topic. If you have any questions, aks here!

Comment: Thanks, great explanation! Is it possible to 'search' for the province code though, if someone types "100 john street, toronto, on, canada" then it's going to capitalize CANADA instead?

Comment: @Matthew I added one more way to solve it, this time for more kind of strings. The solution is not trivial. If you are using php7, I guess you will have to change something once the "\e" in the end of the regex is not supported on php 7. However, on php 5 it will work just fine.

Comment: This is a really great solution you've added actually. I'm going to use this! So what does the \e do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "relations map" array in such manner `array('toronto' =>'ON', ...)` to define which province the certain town is related to:

```
function findProvCode($address_data) {
    $prov_codes = array('toronto' =>'ON', 'NL','PE','NS','NB','QC','MB','SK','AB','BC','YT','NT','NU');
    $words = explode(" ", ucwords($address_data));
    $last_index = count($words) - 1;

    if (in_array(strtoupper($words[$last_index]), $prov_codes)) {
        $words[$last_index] = strtoupper($words[$last_index]);        
    } elseif (array_key_exists(strtolower($words[$last_index]), $prov_codes)) {
        $words[] = $prov_codes[strtolower($words[$last_index])];
    }
    return implode(" ", $words);
}

echo findProvCode("100 john st., toronto, on") . "<br>";
echo findProvCode("100 john st., toronto");
```

The output:

```
100 John St., Toronto, ON
100 John St., Toronto ON
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you specifically asked about string manipulation, this is one way to do it using (mostly) string functions.

```
$codes = array('NL','PE','NS','NB','QC','ON','MB','SK','AB','BC','YT','NT','NU');

$province = strtoupper(substr($address, -2));        // take last 2 chars and convert to UC
if (in_array($province, $codes)) {                   // try to find it in the codes array
    $address = substr($address, 0, -2) . $province;  // replace last 2 chars with UC version
}
```

Not *only* string functions because I don't think there really is a better way than `in_array` to verify that a string is part of a certain set of strings. You could do something like

```
if (strpos('NL|PE|NS|NB|QC|ON|MB|SK|AB|BC|YT|NT|NU', $province) !== false) { ...
```

but regardless of the delimiter used, matching an arbitrary string against a longer string instead of an array of strings can theoretically yield false positives.

Comment: For sure, I'm learning that this is quite difficult to do efficiently... for example you're proposing to remove the last 2 characters of the string, assuming that those 2 characters are what we need to remove.  If someone puts "100 John st., Toronto, on, canada" then wouldn't it just remove "da" from "canada"? Ideally you'd want the ability to search for what you want to find, then delete it, which in_array seems good for.